# Conditional action based on file input (shiny)

Tags: r, input, shiny

I have a shiny app in which you can upload an excel sheet.
The code is like this:

```
 fileInput("file1", "Choose file:",
                multiple = FALSE,
                accept = ".xlsx")
```

Now I want to add another `fileInput` that is an optional (!) dataset. If I don't choose a file, the first dataset should be as is. If I choose a file, the first dataset should only contain those observations that are not in the optional second dataset based on one variable. Something like `Data1[!Var %in% Data2[, Var]]`. The only thing I want to know is: How can I formulate the condition if a file is uploaded? Something like `if(is_uploaded(input$file2))`.

Answer (score 1):

When a file is uploaded, the associated input is not `NULL`. So you can do

```
if(!is.null(input$file2))
```

Comment: How easy was that? Works fine! Thank you so much!